# How to add analytics code in React Native lifecycle

Tags: react-native

I have a `TabBarIOS` which contains five navigators. I need to track each view on screen for google analytics, but ReactNative doesn't provide a lifecycle for that.

I'v tried to track in the `componentDidMount` of those views, but it will be only called once in its lifecycle for each view. Switching between tabs will not trigger `componentDidMount` again.

Furthermore, when I `push()`/`pop()` a view into/from a navigator, I need a callback to find which component will be shown.

Is there any callback method or delegate method which would be called when a component is going to show (like `-viewDidAppear:` in iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

TabBarIOS.Item has a property named [onPress()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios-item.html#onpress) that gets called when the item is pressed. You can use this callback to update analytics.

Comment: I want to use aspect-oriented way to inject code into a target method to avoid high coupling. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to hook `onPress()` thought its prototype.